# Using Queue en C# .NET

Tags: c#

In a queue I have some methods and functions where I assign the rank of the queue and where I enter the values (shifts) that will fill that range, but I have a problem where I have not been able to solve it and it is the following, when filling the queue with the values (shifts) that I enter do not know what to do with the next turn that comes since at that time the queue is full and when I finish the turn that is inside the queue I spend the next turn I had waiting for.

```
public BancosBb(int max)
    {
        frente = -1;
        atras = -1;                     
        maximoTodasCajas = max;           
        laCola = new int[maximoTodasCajas];           

    }
    public Boolean CajaLlenaCajaBB()
    {
        if (atras == maximoTodasCajas - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
    public Boolean CajaVaciaCajaBB()
    {
        if (frente == maximoTodasCajas - 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void Agregar_ColaCajaBB(int n)
    {
        if (CajaLlenaCajaBB() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La caja 1 esta llena");
        }
        else
        {
            atras++;
            laCola[atras] = n;
            if (atras == 0)
            {
                frente = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public int Del_ColaCajaBB()
    {
        int n = -777;
        if (CajaVaciaCajaBB() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La caja 1 esta vacia");
        }
        else
        {
            n = laCola[frente];
            if (frente == atras)
            {
                frente = -1;
                atras = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                frente++;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

Comment: There os Queue data structure if you only want to use queuing mechanism.

Comment: Friend, what happens is that at the time of having the queues full of several boxes, I don't know where to put the other shifts that arrive since the queues are still filling, is it good to implement a table in the database where I can save those shifts what are they coming ?.
.

Comment: Yep if the queue is expected to get bigger then you can consider having data added to table and may be even get rid of code based queuing mechanism. 
You can always run task to process queued items in database table.
If the processing does not need to be real time, database table items can be cleared during off peak hour of system.

Comment: Hemant, thanks for the input, it helped me a lot.